# Breaking a unordered list in to two

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to break up a dynamic unordered list after the fifth li by year using pure css. Without Js/Jquery.

I attached a image to show example. [Example Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCrey.png)

html

```
<ul id="year">
   <li><a href="#">2016</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">2015</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">2014</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">2013</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">2012</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">2011</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">2010</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">2009</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">2008</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">2007</a></li>
</ul>
```

css

```
ul#year {
   margin-top: 20px;

   li {
       margin-bottom: 20px;
       background-color: blue;
       width: 50%;
       float: left;
       a {
           @include regular-bold;
           color: $darkGray;
       }
   }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I know this might seem kinda straight forward... but why not just use 2 `ul`'s instead of 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the ul in a two-column class and add this css.

```
.two-column {
   @include column-count(2);
}

ul#year {
   li {
      margin-top: 20px;
   }
}



<div class="two-column">
                                <ul id="year">
                                    <li><a href="#">2016</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">2015</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">2014</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">2013</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">2012</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">2011</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">2010</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">2009</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">2008</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">2007</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of li's is known, you can use `transform` to shift the others to the right and up:

```
ul li:nth-child(n+6){
  transform: translateX(70px) translateY(-5.95em)
}
```

http://codepen.io/jshawl/pen/vKvkbQ

Answer (score 0):

You can just use 2 divs and use the float property.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>

        <style>
            ul{
                padding: 10px;
                margin: 10px;
                width: 100px;
            }

            #a{
                float: left;
            }

            #b{
                float: right;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <div id="a">
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
            </div>

            <div id="b">
                <li>4</li>
                <li>5</li>
                <li>6</li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```